# undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume' when compiling C++ code with clang++ using Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, clang

As descriped in the title, I download Android NDK from https://developer.android.google.cn/ndk/downloads/index.html and use clang toolchains to compile my test code, but I got errors like this:

```
========== [CC] ==========
mkdir -p  /home/projects/llvm/out
/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang --target=aarch64-linux-android -O2 -std=c99 -B/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29  -c src/a.c -o /home/projects/llvm/out/a.o
========== [LINK] ==========
mkdir -p /home/projects/llvm/out
/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld -L/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/platforms/android-29/arch-arm64/usr/lib -L/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 -lc -e main /home/projects/llvm/out/a.o -o /home/projects/llvm/out/a.elf
========== [CPP] ==========
mkdir -p  /home/projects/llvm/out
/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang++ --target=aarch64-linux-android -O2 -std=gnu++98 -B/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 -I/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/clang-include -c src/b.cpp -o /home/projects/llvm/out/b.o
========== [LINK] ==========
mkdir -p /home/projects/llvm/out
/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld -L/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/platforms/android-29/arch-arm64/usr/lib -L/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 -L/home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android -rpath-link /home/projects/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 -lc -lc++ -lc++_shared -lc++abi -lstdc++ -e main /home/projects/llvm/out/b.o -o /home/projects/llvm/out/b.elf
/home/projects/llvm/out/b.o: In function `main':
b.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/home/projects/llvm/out/b.o: In function `std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >& std::__ndk1::operator>><char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >(std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >&)':
b.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6__ndk1rsIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS_13basic_istreamIT_T0_EES9_RNS_12basic_stringIS6_S7_T1_EE[_ZNSt6__ndk1rsIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEERNS_13basic_istreamIT_T0_EES9_RNS_12basic_stringIS6_S7_T1_EE]+0x214): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/home/projects/llvm/out/b.o: In function `std::__ndk1::basic_ostream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(double)':
b.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6__ndk113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEElsEd[_ZNSt6__ndk113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEElsEd]+0x1b4): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/home/projects/llvm/out/b.o: In function `std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >& std::__ndk1::__input_arithmetic_with_numeric_limits<int, char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >(std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >&, int&)':
b.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6__ndk138__input_arithmetic_with_numeric_limitsIicNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_istreamIT0_T1_EES7_RT_[_ZNSt6__ndk138__input_arithmetic_with_numeric_limitsIicNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_istreamIT0_T1_EES7_RT_]+0x144): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/home/projects/llvm/out/b.o: In function `std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)':
b.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6__ndk113basic_istreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryC2ERS3_b[_ZNSt6__ndk113basic_istreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryC2ERS3_b]+0x1cc): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/home/projects/llvm/out/b.o:b.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6__ndk113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5flushEv[_ZNSt6__ndk113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5flushEv]+0xf0): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
make: *** [/home/projects/llvm/out/b.elf] Error 1
```

this is the simple test:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── a.c
    └── b.cpp

1 directory, 3 files
```

Makefile:

```
ROOT := /home/projects
NDK := $(ROOT)/android-ndk-r20
TOOLCHAIN := $(NDK)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
TARGET_ARCH := aarch64-linux-android
ANDROID_API_LEVEL := 29

CC := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)$(ANDROID_API_LEVEL)-clang
CPP := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)$(ANDROID_API_LEVEL)-clang++
LD := $(TOOLCHAIN)/bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)-ld

AFLAGS := --target=$(TARGET_ARCH) -O2 -std=c99 \
    -B$(TOOLCHAIN)/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 \

BFLAGS := --target=$(TARGET_ARCH) -O2 -std=gnu++98 \
    -B$(TOOLCHAIN)/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 \
    -I$(TOOLCHAIN)/clang-include

ALDFLAGS := -L$(NDK)/platforms/android-29/arch-arm64/usr/lib \
    -L$(TOOLCHAIN)/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 \
    -lc -e main

BLDFLAGS := -L$(NDK)/platforms/android-29/arch-arm64/usr/lib \
    -L$(TOOLCHAIN)/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 \
    -L$(TOOLCHAIN)/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android \
    -rpath-link $(TOOLCHAIN)/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 \
    -lc -lc++ -lc++_shared -lc++abi -lstdc++ -e main

BUILD_DIR := $(ROOT)/llvm/out

SRC_C := $(wildcard src/*.c)
SRC_CPP := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
C_TARGET := a.elf
CPP_TARGET := b.elf
C_OBJS := $(notdir $(SRC_C:%.c=%.o))
CPP_OBJS := $(notdir $(SRC_CPP:%.cpp=%.o))
TARGETS := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(C_TARGET) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CPP_TARGET)

_all: $(TARGETS)
    @echo
    @ls -al out

# C
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(C_TARGET): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(C_OBJS)
    @echo "========== [LINK] =========="
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(LD) $(ALDFLAGS) -v $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(C_OBJS): $(SRC_C)
    @echo "========== [CC] =========="
    mkdir -p  $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(AFLAGS) -v -c $< -o $@

# CPP
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CPP_TARGET): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CPP_OBJS)
    @echo "========== [LINK] =========="
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(LD) $(BLDFLAGS) -v $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CPP_OBJS): $(SRC_CPP)
    @echo "========== [CPP] =========="
    mkdir -p  $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CPP) $(BFLAGS) -v -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

b.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    int n;
    std::cin>>n>>s;
    std::cout<<"sqrt(n) = "<<sqrt(n)<<", s = "<<s<<endl;
}
```

It's strange that C code could compile correctly but C++ could not, I finally figured out it is "cin" and "cout" in b.cpp that cause this error, the compile will success if use "scanf" and "printf" instead. But I can compile and run the code with gcc, so the code is not to blame.

I tried to add -lgcc_s to LDFLAGS but it's not included in the NDK, ld can't find it, is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: I do a fair amount of NDK building using the supplied toolchains. The builds always include `--systroot`. For the latest NDKs I believe it should be `$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot`. I also use `-funwind-tables -fexceptions -frtti` for C++ projects. Since you are having trouble with `_Unwind_Resume`, you should try at least `-funwind-tables`.

Comment: And one other thing... You should always set `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in your scripts or projects. The NDK tools use the variables. Also see [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/Szy_KYY9GcwJ) on the Android NDK mailing list.

Comment: tried, still receiving these errors =_= , but thanks anyway. This is a simple test, you can try it on your NDK environment if that's not too much to ask.

Comment: Your makefile is quite a bit more complicated than it needs to be, and mistakes there could be part of the problem. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems

Answer (score 1):

> use clang toolchains to compile my test code, but I got errors like this...

This is more than I can fit into a comment, but it does not answer the question. This will help you fix the problem.

When building from the command line using the NDK you have to use the same toolchain and same command line options as the NDK. You are not doing that, and your C++ flags really diverge from what Android uses. All NDK's I am aware of use `--sysroot` and C++ source files use `-funwind-tables -fexceptions -frtti`. NDK r19 and NDK r20 use `-std=c++11` for C++ files. And the latest NDKs are setting `__ANDROID_API__`, like `-D__ANDROID_API__=21`.

I build Crypto++ and OpenSSL from the command line for Android. The procedure works when you use the same toolchain and same command line options as the NDK. Here are my crib notes for building Crypto++, which is another C++ library: [Android_(Command_Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)).

You need to step back, clone Google's NDK Samples GitHub, checkout the android-mk branch, and build the Hello World program. Take note of the compiler options. Use the same compiler options in your project.

Here is how you perform the clone and build the sample:

```sh
android$ git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk
android$ cd android-ndk
android$ git checkout android-mk
android$ cd hello-jni

android:hello-jni$ ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-29 V=1
...
```

---

> ```
> BFLAGS := --target=$(TARGET_ARCH) -O2 -std=gnu++98 \
>     -B$(TOOLCHAIN)/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29 \
>     -I$(TOOLCHAIN)/clang-include
> ```

Seriously? `-std=gnu++98`?

I hope that was a artifact leftover from testing.

You might want to have a look at some of the Andoid NDK docs. Maybe start with [C++ Library Support](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support). Android NDK r19 and NDK r20 use LLVM's `libc++`. The GNU gear is gone. If you want the GNU gear, then drop back to a lesser NDK like r12 or r16.

---

> (From the comments): This is a simple test, you can try it on your NDK environment if that's not too much to ask...

It is not simple. You have to set the environment, create the source files and the run the build. You are also missing your `a.*` files. You should provide a GitHub repo with the everything setup and a script that runs your build process.

---

Here is the output from NDK r19 and android-28. Notice how much different your options are from the options Google uses. Pay attention to the details of lines like ***`[arm64-v8a] Compile`***.

```sh
android:hello-jni$ ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-28 V=1 clean &>/dev/null

android:hello-jni$ ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-28 V=1

Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-28 is higher than android:minSdkVersion 3 in ./AndroidManifest.xml. NDK binaries will *not* be compatible with devices older than android-28. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md for more information.    
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/* ./libs/x86_64/* ./libs/armeabi-v7a/* ./libs/x86/*
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver ./libs/x86_64/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
[arm64-v8a] Gdbserver      : [aarch64-linux-android] libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver
install -p /opt/android-ndk-r19c/prebuilt/android-arm64/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver
[arm64-v8a] Gdbsetup       : libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/arm64-v8a" > ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
echo "directory /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot jni /opt/android-ndk-r19c/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
[x86_64] Gdbserver      : [x86_64-linux-android] libs/x86_64/gdbserver
install -p /opt/android-ndk-r19c/prebuilt/android-x86_64/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/x86_64/gdbserver
[x86_64] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/x86_64" > ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
echo "directory /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot jni /opt/android-ndk-r19c/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
install -p /opt/android-ndk-r19c/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a" > ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "directory /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot jni /opt/android-ndk-r19c/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[x86] Gdbserver      : [i686-linux-android] libs/x86/gdbserver
install -p /opt/android-ndk-r19c/prebuilt/android-x86/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver
[x86] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/x86" > ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
echo "directory /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot jni /opt/android-ndk-r19c/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
rm -f ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d -target aarch64-none-linux-android28 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -fno-addrsig -fpic -O0 -UNDEBUG -fno-limit-debug-info  -Ijni   -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -c  jni/hello-jni.c -o ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -Wl,-soname,libhello-jni.so -shared ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o -lgcc -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -latomic -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -target aarch64-none-linux-android28 -no-canonical-prefixes    -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings   -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so
install -p ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so ./libs/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so
[x86_64] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
rm -f ./obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d -target x86_64-none-linux-android28 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -fno-addrsig -fPIC -O0 -UNDEBUG -fno-limit-debug-info  -Ijni   -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -c  jni/hello-jni.c -o ./obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
[x86_64] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -Wl,-soname,libhello-jni.so -shared ./obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o -lgcc -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -latomic -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -target x86_64-none-linux-android28 -no-canonical-prefixes    -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings   -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/x86_64/libhello-jni.so
[x86_64] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/x86_64/libhello-jni.so
install -p ./obj/local/x86_64/libhello-jni.so ./libs/x86_64/libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/x86_64/libhello-jni.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
rm -f ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi28 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -fno-addrsig -fpic -mfpu=vfpv3-d16  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -O0 -UNDEBUG -fno-limit-debug-info  -mfpu=neon -Ijni   -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -c  jni/hello-jni.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -Wl,-soname,libhello-jni.so -shared ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o -lgcc -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -latomic -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi28 -no-canonical-prefixes    -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings    -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so
install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so
[x86] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
rm -f ./obj/local/x86/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/x86/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d -target i686-none-linux-android28 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot /opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -fno-addrsig -fPIC -O0 -UNDEBUG -fno-limit-debug-info  -Ijni   -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -c  jni/hello-jni.c -o ./obj/local/x86/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -Wl,-soname,libhello-jni.so -shared ./obj/local/x86/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o -lgcc -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -latomic -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -target i686-none-linux-android28 -no-canonical-prefixes    -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings   -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/x86/libhello-jni.so
[x86] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/x86/libhello-jni.so
install -p ./obj/local/x86/libhello-jni.so ./libs/x86/libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/x86/libhello-jni.so
```